# Is there anything similar to livechange in DateRangeSelection control?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there any livechange method option like input field? When user choose date and after that click on enter it should search instead of go and click on search button.

```
<DateRangeSelection id="devDate" displayFormat="MM-dd-yyyy" valueStateText="Delivery Date must not be empty. Date format MM-dd-yyyy" valueFormat="MM-dd-yyyy" liveChange="handleLiveChange">
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S11"/>
    </layoutData>
</DateRangeSelection>
```

Thanks and Regards
RK

Comment: the "change" event is what will do the thing for you!

Comment: Thanks Nandan for your reply..I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: The change as @NandanChaturvedi suggested is the only available option currently. I see in the [DateRangeSelection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DateRangeSelection/preview) sample that it does give the date immediately after I choose 2 dates for a range, so what sort of a "liveChange" are you looking for? If want to perform search once the date range is selected, you can use the [`fireSearch`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SearchField/methods/fireSearch) method within the change function.